# Blocking even days in Months with even number of days (JQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have to make Datepicker which will work like this: If the selected month has even number of days(30) all the even days in the month will be blocked to pick(2,4,6...) etc. If the selected month has odd number of days(31), all the odd days in the datepicker will be blocked to pick(1,3,5..) etc.

My problem is that i don't know how to block the even and the odd days, i know only how to block the whole month, but not any day in particular... 
Disclaimer: I know that there is already something posted like how to block particular day, but not anything with even or odd days.

Here is my code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: nationalDays});
  });

 function nationalDays(date){
 var x = date.getMonth();
 var r = x%2;
 if(r == 0){
    return [false];
 }
else if(r == 1){
    return [true];
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option, You can check whether the date should be enabled or not and set the first item in the array being returned to  `true`/`false`. True will enable the item while false will disable it, as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var disabled = true, // date enabled by default
        // get the number of days in current month
        numOfDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
      if (numOfDays % 2 == 0)
        disabled = (date.getDate() % 2 != 0) // for even-days months, disable the even dates
      else disabled = (date.getDate() % 2 == 0) //for odd - days months, disable the odd dates
      return [disabled, ""]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>
```